# How to return Custom RepeatStatus from spring Batch step

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Step Class: GenerateReferenceNumber

```
package com.npst.imps.action;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import com.npst.imps.utils.TransactionResponseData;
public class GenerateReferenceNumber implements Tasklet {
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {    
    double rrn= Math.random();
    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("rrn", rrn);   
    double tid= (double) chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("tid");       
    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("trnsactionstatus", "RRN generated for Tid::"+tid+" is "+rrn);
    TransactionResponseData transactionResponseData =(TransactionResponseData) chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get("transactionResponseData");
    transactionResponseData.setRrn(rrn+"");
    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("transactionResponseData", transactionResponseData); 

          return RepeatStatus.FINISHED; 
    }

}
```

Instead of Repeatstatus.FINISHED , how can I return my own defined status and based on them the next step will be decided. Custom status like success, fail, partial etc.

batchjob.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd">
       <job id="MBSFT">
         <step id="PrepareTid" allow-start-if-complete="true" next="PrepareRRN">
            <tasklet ref="PrepareTransactionId" />
        </step>

        <step id="PrepareRRN" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <tasklet ref="GenerateReferenceNumber" />
                <next on="COMPLETED" to="IdentifyImpsService" />
        </step>

        <step id="IdentifyImpsService" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <tasklet ref="IdentifyIMPSRequestType" />
            <next on="COMPLETED" to="FetchNBIN" />
        </step>

        <step id="FetchNBIN" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <tasklet ref="FetchNBINFromIFSC" />
        </step>
    </job>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can easily send custom status from `StepExecutionListener`.
ExitStatus is simple enum. You can pass any string as Exit status.

Decide your batch flow based on exist status.

Below is sample java config code.

```
  //Return status from step listener
      @Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            if(condition1)
            return new ExitStatus("CUSTOM_STATUS");     
            if(condition2)
            return new ExitStatus("CUSTOM_STATUS_XYZ");     
            if(condition3)
            return new ExitStatus.COMPLETED
}


@Bean
    public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs) throws Exception {
        return jobs.get("myJob")
                .start(Step1())
                .next(Step2()).on("CUSTOM_STATUS").to(step3())
                .next(Step2()).on("CUSTOM_STATUS_XYZ").to(step4())
                .next(Step2())).on("COMPLETED").to(step4())             
                .build()
                .listener(listener)
                .preventRestart()
                .build();

    }
```

Comment: @NaveenKumarMishra  Could you please accept the answer if it helped  you  ? so that others  having same issue can use same solution  :)

Comment: But what the reason to return custom status? Who handles this status ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is not possible.
You may put your custom return status into StepExecution, use an [ExecutionContextPromotionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ExecutionContextPromotionListener.html) to move property from step to job execution context and than use a [JobExecutionDecider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) to redirect flow.